# how to make values of column in entity class as lower case while storing using Annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, hana

> I want an entity class through which I can store data to DB, for
>   specific columns I want in case-sensitive, is there any annotation to
>   be used above these specific columns to store as requested? please let
>   me if the question is not clear,Thanks in advance.

```
@Column(name = "EMAIL",unique=true)  //i want store this email id as lower case,
private String email;               //never mind in what case user enters
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `@ColumnTransformer`

```
 @Column(name = "email") 
@ColumnTransformer(write = "LOWER(email)") 
 private String email;
```

Comment: tanq for spending your valuable time on my query,but the exception populated is:- 
 @WriteExpression must contain exactly one value placeholder ('?') character: property [demo] and column [`email`]

Comment: can you paste the complete stacktrace...?

Answer (score 0):

I try this and it works:

```
@Column
@ColumnTransformer(write = "LOWER(?)") 
private String email;
```

expression of @ColumnTransformer.write would replace the original "?" placeholder in persisting sql statement. So must provide a compliant-sql expression with "?":

```
insert into member (email) values (?)

---->

insert into member (email) values (LOWER(?))
```

detail usage: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/ColumnTransformer.html

Comment: Add Some details, so it would helpful for beginner also. Add explanation for Annotations